# Minimum Deployment Target for IOS Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an application in appstore with minimum deployment target 7.0.
Now due to customer requirement for IOS 6.0 I want to upload a new version with IOS 6.0 as minimum target.

Is it possible??

Comment: Has your client/customer seen the stats for who is left on iOS6? it is an extremely low % more hassle than it's worth for changing it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Just change your minimum deployment target to 6.0, update your code to run on iOS 6, and then deploy.

You'll probably have to do a lot of work to make your app work and look good in both versions. Make sure to test extensively.

Comment: For a RN project, different RN libraries have different min iOS version. What's the best way to identify the minimum deployment iOS version for a RN project?